# Regular Expression: Match betwen a long string with unknown symbol too

Tags: regex, web-crawler

I have string and it is more than 1000+ character.. my character like this.

```
<div class='a-body__content has-bbcode'>
    <p class="bb-p"><span class="bb-dropcap bb-dropcap--letter">d Paola all  joined the company after the war, and took oin 1966 to a young designer – the then-unknown, Paris-based Karl Lagerfeld – who took over the aesthetics of the family company and now works with Silvia Venturini Fendi, Anna’s daughter.</p>   
    ---- more 1000+ character 
<div class="footer
```

My actual string too long then I showed an example, you may notice, in the string, there is some special character. and in entire string, too many special characters like these

I am trying to grab `<div class='a-body__content` to `<div class="footer`

I know I can grab that special character with `.*` but after an space, it cant match next character after space, but if I do like `.*\s.*\s.*`, my patter becomes too long and it will work only for this string and will not works other string of this type, so I need a solution to grab any character between `<div class='a-body__content` to `<div class="footer` and so that it works for any other string of this type.

Can anyone help me with this case?

Comment: **to grab** - not "grabe" ....

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, it i did it like this `[\s\S]+` thanks